# Mongoid self reference with properties for users friendships status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, many-to-many, mongoid, entity-relationship

Using Mongo and Rails, I would to build a friendship system like facebook:
- Before making the friendship, the use must accept the friendship request

I found a lots of code to do the relationship but never with a relation's property...

Do you have any idea or clue how to do that to be "respectful" of the NoSQL concept

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use two models, something like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :friendships
end

class Friendship
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
  field :pending, :type => Boolean, :default => true
end
```

Does it sound good? Hope this helps!

Comment: how do u load the friends of a user after the friendship is created? We cant use 'through' in mongoid.

Answer (score 6):

I had to put in my User model:

```
has_many :friendships, :inverse_of => :owner
```

Check out associations in the documentation http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common